# Cordova : Error when building Ionic1 app to iOS platform

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to emulate an Ionic1 app in iOS, but the build command is giving me errors and I don't know how to fix it. What should I do?

**$ ionic info**

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.0
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0 
    Gulp CLI              : CLI version 3.9.1 Local version 3.9.1

local packages:

    Cordova Platforms : ios 4.5.4
    Ionic Framework   : ionic1 1.3.4

System:

    ios-deploy : 1.9.2 
    ios-sim    : 6.1.2 
    Node       : v8.1.2
    npm        : 5.6.0 
    OS         : OS X Yosemite
    Xcode      : Xcode 7.1 Build version 7B91b 

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : not set

Misc:

    backend : legacy
```

**$ cordova plugins list**

```
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.4 "Device"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.1.16 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.3 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.1 "Whitelist"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
```

I've tried:

```
$ sudo npm install -g ios-sim
$ ionic cordova platform add ios
$ ionic cordova build ios
```

and got the following error message:

**Error**

```
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /Users/otero/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/conFusion-fibudfuhdifeioamjwrjiuwgycdy/Build/Intermediates/conFusion.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/conFusion.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GCDWebServerDataRequest.o conFusion/Plugins/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview/GCDWebServerDataRequest.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
(node:547) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/otero/Google Drive/coursera/full stack web development/course 4/ionic/conFusion/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-workspace,conFusion.xcworkspace,-scheme,conFusion,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,-destination,platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6s Plus,build,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/otero/Google Drive/coursera/full stack web development/course 4/ionic/conFusion/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/otero/Google Drive/coursera/full stack web development/course 4/ionic/conFusion/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
(node:547) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution posted here worked for me:
https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview/issues/42

Looking at the error log, I've found the error was:

```
ionic/conFusion/platforms/ios/conFusion/Plugins/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview/GCDWebServerDataRequest.m:59:10: error: no visible @interface for 'NSData' declares the selector 'appendData:'
  [_data appendData:data];
```

Then I just had to find the respective .h file and edit one line:

```
//from this: @property(nonatomic, readonly) NSData* data;
@property(nonatomic, readonly) NSMutableData* data; //to this
```

And then run `$ ionic cordova build ios` again. And it worked.

From the author of the post:

> I did some more research and made a small tweak to the underlying
>   library and fixed the issue. But I dont know if it is necessarily
>   correct. The public interface in the .h file did not match the private
>   interface in the .m file. There is an @property named "data" that is
>   of type NSData in the .h file and of type NSMutableData in the .m
>   file. When I change the data @property to NSMutable in the .h file,
>   the ionic build command works again.
>
> I have dabbled in objective-C but never totally understood the
>   @interface, @property, and synthesize syntax for declaring things. I
>   don't know if the .h and .m need to match. I made this change because
>   I noticed that the NSData object does not have an appendData: method
>   but the NSMutableData does. You can try for yourself and see if this
>   works.